# Apple app site association file on azure app service (Spring Boot + Angular WebApp)

Tags: ios, spring-boot, azure, spring-mvc, deep-linking

I have a backend hosted on Azure AppService (linux) which is a SpringBoot 3 Application.
I put an `apple-app-site-association.json` file to /static/ and added a WebMvcConfigurer like that:

```
override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {

        // web in jar
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(object : PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Throws(IOException::class)
                    override fun getResource(resourcePath: String, location: Resource): Resource? {
                        val requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath)
                        return if (requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable) {
                            requestedResource
                        }
                        // env dependent file for ios universal deeplinks
                        else if (resourcePath == "apple-app-site-association") {
                            ClassPathResource("/static/apple-app-site-association-${environment.activeProfiles.first()}.json")
                        }
                        else {
                            ClassPathResource("/static/web/index.html")
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
```

I often read that .json should not be included in the filename, however I have some trouble setting the content-type with this resourcehandler and I am not sure if it is also necessary when it is done like this since the https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ validates the domain.

The app gets the error `Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data` in the device console when the app gets installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem was not the approach how the file is served but the file itself.
The `teamId` was missing in the `appId` field of the file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "<teamId>.app.id.dev"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "#": "no_universal_links",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
          },
          {
            "/": "/link/*",
            "comment": "comment"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```